# nBuilder alternative for Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, builder, nbuilder

Is there any tool like [nBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) for java?

I want to build objects for unit testing and I dont want to have one builder class for each entity in my domain.

I am currently using mockito but it doesnt replace the functionality of [nBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/).

Answer (score 4):

You can try DataFactory: [Generate test data with DataFactory](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/generate-test-data-with-datafactory/)

Also I found this poject at google code that could be helpful: [Random Data Generator](http://code.google.com/p/random-data-generator/)

They are not equivalent to nBuilder, but they try to provide similar functionality to the one provided by nBuilder. It's not a perfect replacement but is the closer I could find.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Neither of the libraries are equivalent to nBuilder.

Comment: @Mohayemin They are not equivalent, but they try to provide similar  functionality to the one provided by nBuilder. It's not a perfect replacement but is the closer I could find.

Comment: Yes, thats true. But U did not mention this in your answer. That is why I was misguided. Can you please edit your answer so that the same does not happen to someone else? Also, I can take away my downvote.

Comment: @Mohayemin You are right, I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointed this :)

Answer (score 3):

TestNG has @DataProvider and @Factory.

Comment: I like your answer, but it's not nearly fully fleshed out.  I'll look into `@Factory` and the TestNG framework more closely.

Answer (score 2):

While not strictly matching what you want with nBuilder, I'd strongly recommend looking into the Spock testing framework.  It has very strong mocking and stubbing tools built into it, and one of the greatest perks of Spock is Data Driven testing.

http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/data_driven_testing.html

I find data driven testing to be some of the most efficient unit testing I've come across, to date.  I don't know if this will directly replace the kinds of things nBuilder can do, but I can tell you that my unit testing is much more thorough (and easier to write) with Spock.

Answer (score 1):

CodePro JUnit Test Case Generation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with nBuilder, but it looks to have some overlap with QuickBuilder - a project I put together that generates on the fly implementations of test data builders to interfaces you supply.

https://github.com/hcoles/QuickBuilder

It has some support for producing sequences of values, but does not generate values for you as nBuilder seems to.

Also, similar in functionality to QuickBuilder but presenting a different interface is, makeiteasy

https://code.google.com/p/make-it-easy/